# How to stop a running GCP Cloud Task?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there some way to stop a *running* Cloud Task? I accidentally started a task which is processing a lot of data and don't see a way to stop it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Up there you'll see two choices: `Pause Queue` `Delete Queue`.

Comment: Those look like the obvious choices, but they seem to apply only to items in the queue, not running tasks. The task ended up finishing after awhile. It would be nice to know how to stop it for the future though.

Comment: I thought you just didn't see it xD

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doc,](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/deleting-appengine-queues-and-tasks) you cannot pause the task itself, just the queue. If you pause the queue, it should pause the task as well, or, you can just delete the task.

And, as commented on the other anwer this is all manage by the UI the command line is still in [Alpha](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/tasks/queues/pause)